# MAUI how to use clip

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

Can any one one explain how to use clip geometry and imagesource/button etc in the next scenario:

1. Load an image from disk and show on display -> `DONE!`
2. Over the image show a crop bounds as a clip geometry -> `DONE!`
3. Save the image and geometry -> `DONE!`
4. On another page place in a grid image container. Fill the container with the IMAGE CROPPING RESULT -> `PROBLEM!`

Are there ways to do this without saving a cropped image, just using the image path and clip geometry????

Comment: Please show some code, explain in sufficient detail what you've tried and what's going wrong and provide the errors you see (as text). Maybe also read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there ways to do this without saving a cropped image, just using
> the image path and clip geometry????

Yes, you can use the `Clip with a Geometry`.

The VisualElement class has a Clip property, of type Geometry, that defines the outline of the contents of an element. When the Clip property is set to a Geometry object, only the area that is within the region of the Geometry will be visible.

The following example shows how to use a Geometry object as the clip region for an Image:

```
<Image Source="monkeyface.png">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="100"
                         RadiusY="100"
                         Center="180,180" />
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Comment: The OP should clarify the problem as it's not clear what the issue is.